# Receiving an Uncaught (in promise) undefined error when loading an instagram embed via iframe

Tags: html, iframe, instagram, embed, uncaught-exception

I am trying to integrate instagram embeds into my PHP website, and they work as expected, but I run into the following errors in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox whenever they load:

```
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
__________

ErrorUtils caught an error:

Non-object thrown: undefined
```

Example html and scss I am using are as follows (the error occurs without the scss as well btw):

```
html:
<iframe class='ig-post' src='https://www.instagram.com/p/CN7oZDALwoL/embed'></iframe>


scss: 
.ig-post{
  background:#FFF;
  display: block;
  border:0; 
  border-radius:3px; 
  box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); 
  margin: 1px; 
  height: 655px;
  padding:0; 
  width:450px;
  min-width: 300px; 
  @media(max-width: 500px){
    width: 300px;
    height: 505px;
  }
}
```

I have tried the onload and onerror attributes, but those did not help. What can I do to prevent these error from showing up on the console?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the error is coming from the iframe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I couldn't find anything in my code base that was throwing the error. And it only occurs when the iframe tag has an instagram link. No errors show up when I use a youtube link.

Comment: I was also able to produce the same error when rendering it on an html file in a different environment